# calling citeparser function in python

Tags: python, function, loops

I wrote the following function:

```
def CiteParser():
    with open("/tmp/content.txt") as myfile:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile)
        for cite in soup.find_all('cite'):
            print cite.string
```

Now I want to call it in my program like this:

```
result = open("/tmp/result.txt", "a+")
res = CiteParser()
result.write(str(res))
result.close()
```

I have also another function that appends url content to `/tmp/content.txt` and I put `CiteParser` into a loop.

But it returns always `same` result for me..
Am I calling CiteParser correctly? if not how is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing strings, you need to **return** it.

```
def CiteParser():
    with open("/tmp/content.txt") as myfile:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile)
        result = []
        for cite in soup.find_all('cite'):
            result.append(cite.string)
        return '\n'.join(result)
```

Otherwise, the function return nothing; implicitly return `None`.

Comment: Ok thank you..now I have the error:`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 153-157: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @MortezaLSC, Try `u'\n'` instead of `'\n'`.

Comment: @MortezaLSC, Now in differnt place? right? (`str(res)`)

Comment: when I put \r\n it changes the place...without adding `\r` my traceback is:`raceback (most recent call last):
  File "work6.py", line 84, in <module>
    result.write(str(res))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 153-157: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @MortezaLSC, Try `result.write(res.encode('utf-8'))` (Replace `utf-8` if you need to write in different encoding)

Comment: Thank you...let me check the result

Comment: Very good.It appends the result to result.txt but there is a problem. It just return content of my first page in bing and just append it...

Comment: @MortezaLSC, It maybe because the file `/tmp/content.txt` contain the first page result.

Comment: @MortezaLSC, It deserve separate question. Please post a separate question for that.

Comment: No it gets me all the pages but I think I should set counter to identify pages may be..this is the problem of `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: pardon I have a question can you help me now?

Comment: I want to split each result so I changed you code like this but there is an error: `for cite in soup.find_all('cite'):
            dan = result.append(cite.string)
            dan.split('/')[0]
        return u'\n'.join(dan)`

Comment: @MortezaLSC, It's hard to read the code in the comment. You maybe want this: `result.append(cite.string.split('/')[0])`